# Why do I have to re-download Windows store apps after every reboot?

Tags: windows-store-app

I've got a couple of free apps from the Window store on one machine (I've never used the Windows store on any other machine), but have noticed something very annoying.  The apps will run fine after download, but next time I reboot, they're gone and I have to re-download from the store.

Is that normal (I'd presume not)?  Is there some diagnostic I can run to find out why they're disappearing on reboot?

This is a standard Windows 10 home PC, just recently updated to the latest version of Windows 10, with the same user logging in every time.

Comment: Are you switching users after rebooting the machine? Every time a new user signs in, Windows will re-download all built-in apps. Alternatively, if you're not going to use the built-in apps - Why not remove them altogether?

Comment: What type of device do you use (pc, phone...)? What is your OS and Windows store version? What are those applications? ...

Comment: @Bungicasse I don't understand what you mean about "not going to use the built-in apps" and removing them?  I'm just trying to add apps from the Windows app store, but they vanish every time I reboot...  I want them to stay, but they don't.

Comment: I was never able to resolve this.  I quit using Windows Store apps because it wasn't worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a diagnostic you could attempt to run:

1. Use the Windows Store Apps Troubleshooter

Microsoft has a troubleshooter that scans your system and detects any problems that might be preventing any Windows Store apps from working correctly. Then, if possible, it automatically fixes these without you needing to do anything.

Though the troubleshooter isn’t built-in to Windows, you can easily download it for free from Microsoft’s website. You’ll need a particular version depending on your operating system version, either the Windows 10 download or the Windows 8 download.

Open the file with the Diagnostics Troubleshooting Wizard, which should be selected by default. Then follow the wizard through, clicking Next to progress through the stages.

If problems are detected then the troubleshooter will try to resolve these. It may not be able to fix them or it might not even find any issues in the first place, but it’s definitely worth trying it out anyway.

There are 4 other troubleshooting options as per this website:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-tips-fix-windows-store-app-issues-windows-10/

2. Clear the Store Cache

Clearing the cache of the Store can help resolve issues with installing or updating apps. In fact, clearing cache can resolve many Windows problems. It’s incredibly simple to run and will only take half a minute.

Press Windows Key + R to open Run, then input wsreset.exe and click OK. A blank Command Prompt window will open, but rest assured that it’s clearing the cache. After about ten seconds the window will close and the Store will open automatically.

3. Reset Windows Update Components

If you’re having trouble updating the Store or the apps themselves, you should try resetting the Windows Update components. Handily, there’s a troubleshooter for that! You can grab the right version direct from Microsoft, depending on your operating system, from their support page.

windows update troubleshooter

Run the troubleshooter and click Next to progress through the stages. It’ll automatically detect and fix any problems, if possible. If this doesn’t do the job then check out our guide on resolving Windows Update problems for some other solutions.

4. Edit the Registry for Connection Errors

If you’re getting a connection error when launching the store, downloading an app or updating an app, it might be time to head into the registry. Please ensure you follow these instructions closely because incorrect edits in the registry can cause further problems.

advanced security settings for profiles

First, press Windows Key + R to open Run. Input regedit and click OK. The Registry Editor will open. Using the folders on the left, navigate into the following folder path:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
Right click on Profiles, select Permissions, then click Advanced. Tick Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object and click OK. Now restart your system and hopefully your problem will be resolved.

5. Re-register the Windows Store

The Store app can’t be uninstalled, so the closest we can get is to re-register it on your system. First, perform a system search for powershell, then right click the relevant result and select Run as administrator. Simply put, PowerShell is a scripting environment that can be used to automate tasks.

windows store powershell

If you’re using Windows 10, input the following and then press Enter:

"& {$manifest = (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest}"
If you’re using Windows 8, input this command instead:

Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.XML
You can now close PowerShell and open the Store app, where hopefully your problem will have been resolved.

Comment: So which one of those 5 solutions are you saying will solve the author's problem?  How about providing the information in the body of your answer so we don't have to visit that website.

Comment: [Is downvoting link only answers acceptable?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/500/is-downvoting-link-only-answers-acceptable?rq=1)

Comment: @Ramhound, thank you my friend for pointing this out.